# SQL Server 2012 DBCC memorystatus has wrong information. How can I correct it?

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-7-x64, virtual-memory, dbcc

I have a Windows 7 64-bit machine with 16GB ram, 24GB pagefile, 500GB HD and SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition 64-bit running on it.  I set the Maximum Server Memory to 1024MB through SSMS.

With 5 minutes of starting up, it routinely uses all my virtual memory and triggers warnings on my machine i.e. ProcessExplorer says sqlservr.exe is using Private Bytes of 38GB, Virtual Size of 61GB.

I believe the issue results from mis-information that I can see when I run DBCC MemoryStatus command, which indicates that the **Available Virtual Memory** is **8,763,135,270,912**. This number is at least 8TB. Other stats returned by the command appear to be accurate.

Does anyone know how the DBCC MemoryStatus command gets this number and how I might correct it? I think this would affect how much virtual memory it would try to allocate.

Comment: If you don't get your answer here you might actually have better luck asking on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you have Maximum Server memory configured?

Comment: Thanks Kritner. I've just posted to the dba.stackexchange.com as well.  To Kris, yes I've set the Maximum Server memory to 1024MB.